# Why would a rider ever command any horse attack besides trampling?

Tags: rolemaster, rolemaster-rm2

From Rolemaster *Creatures and Treasures [1]* we gather that Horses (and other draft animals) have several attacks, some for stationary, some for charge attacks.

According to the rules (p. 9):

> Biting and trampling allow the rider to attack also, rearing does not.

When looking at the actual attack tables it seems however, that trampling is really just a lot stronger than any of the other attacks (in terms of damage and crits)...

- Am I missing something? Why would the attack that allows the rider to *also* attack, be the one that does most damage anyway?
- Why would a rider (given a successful riding maneuver to do so) ever tell his horse to use anything beside 'trample' as an attack?

*[1] Creatures and Treasures # RM 1400*

Comment: **Answers to this question are expected to discuss the actual rolemaster rules as they relate to the question asked.** I've now deleted two answers which do nothing but talk about horses in real life, with no visible connection or reference to anything in Rolemaster whatsoever. These kinds of answers are not acceptable, and will continue to be removed.

Comment: As for the "why", you might be looking at a situation where the rider does not *want* to do maximum damage. Picture yourself standing guard on horseback, with a crowd in front of you. Someone is getting brave, and a bit too close for comfort, and you want to scare him off -- making an example, but not killing the fellow outright.

Making your horse take a bite at that somebody would be quite effective, while having it trample him to a pulp might just make the whole situation erupt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had some time to dig through more RM books over the weekend and found the answer, it seems I wasn't careful enough in my study the first time around. (Although this might have to do with our translated German version of the rules also...)

- The *Trample*<sup>1</sup> attacks done by riding/draft animals cannot generally be freely 'chosen' as a mode of attack by the rider.
- However, *Trample* attacks happen in some special cases 'automatically', i.e. the horse will use this attack once certain conditions apply. Namely, these are:

  - For stationary attacks, if a *Rearing*<sup>2</sup> attack ends up doing a non-minor critical damage, the animal will attack using *Trample* in the **next** round.
  - For charging attacks, if a *Ramming*<sup>3</sup> attack ends up doing a non-minor critical damage, the animal will immediately follow up with a *Trample* attack in the **same** round.

Thus, the conundrum of trample attacks is solved: while clearly being the objectively strongest attacks, they can't purposefully be 'triggered' by the rider and are more a matter of luck.

**N.B.** Horses also have a *Biting*<sup>4</sup> attack, that can be chosen when the horse is attacking stationary. This biting attack is generally a bit weaker than the *Rearing* attack and doesn't give the chance of getting a strong *Trample* follow-up -- however, it allows the rider to attack as well, making for a neat little bit of tactical decision making on the side of the player.

*<sup>1</sup> Table used: Trampling

<sup>2</sup> Table used: Crush/Fall

<sup>3</sup> Table used: Ramming/Battering

<sup>4</sup> Table used: Biting*