# Are there (detailed) rules for mounted combat?

Tags: rolemaster, rolemaster-rm2

Our group lately showed increased interest in **mounted combat** (see also my [other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106217/why-would-a-rider-ever-command-any-horse-attack-besides-trampling)). As such we read through the rolemaster source material at our disposal, but weren't really able to find much of anything.

There are combat stats for mounts (riding/draft animals) and there is a single short section in what I think translates to *Arms Law/Claw Law*. Summed up this section - which is really only about one or two paragraphs - states (I am paraphrasing from memory):

- The offensive bonus (OB) of an attacker sitting on top of a mount is essentially a percentage of their normal OB equal to their riding skill.

That's pretty much it it seems. Our group is looking for **more detailed rules for mounted combat**, and - seeing the degree of rules complexity existing in other aspects of Rolemaster - it seems these rules should exist *somewhere*. :)

To give an idea, some questions we'd like answered are for example:

- Are there bonuses/penalties when using certain weapon types from a horse?
- Do mounted attackers get bonuses because of positioning?
- What are the rules surrounding charge attacks (e.g. needed distance, time to accelerate)?
- Are there bonuses/penalties for attackers on foot attacking mounted adversaries?

**Are there detailed rules around mounted combat published in one of the many RM2 source books?**

N.B: We would also be okay with using rules published in **non-RM2 versions** of Rolemaster, as long as these are feasibly compatible - which seems to be the case at least partially [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolemaster#History).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arms law mounted combat (AM&CL #1100) is pretty basic; (Section 5.3) as you've explained.

**Rolemaster Companion 3 (ICE #1700)** *1 expands this somewhat (a few paragraphs of rules) and is directly targeted at the RM2 system.

In this system horses have "Pace categories" and can accelerate 2 categories a round or decelerate 3 categories a round.

Characters in this system get a Charge bonus of:

```
Thrusting weapons: +1 per 10ft/round of speed
Other Weapons: +1 bonus for each 20ft/round of speed.
```

So a lesser warhorse can walk at 90 feet a round and it's maximum pace is dash (x5) for a speed of 450 ft/round (~30 mph)

So at full speed a lesser warhorse would give +45 OB for a thrusting weapon and +22 for a non-thrusting weapon.

Spears set against a charge will recieve the same bonus against the charger.

Horses unable to stop before they hit something recieve fall/crush damage with the charge modifier.

Trained horses charging can attack with their trample attack with the charge bonus added.

The Rolemaster Arms Companion ICE #1120 (RM2 friendly) shockingly doesn't have anything for mounted combat at all.

RMSS doesn't update much beyond RM2 for rules except that a rider can use 10-100% of their action to try and change what a horse is doing each round (otherwise it does the same as last round)

*1 If you get RM3 someone will want to play a Magus. Don't let them. It's a very overpowered class.